# How to use BBands function with (n-1) standard deviation?

Tags: r, standard-deviation

Given the fowling data and results with the BBands function from the TTR package:

```
d1= 1:20
d1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

BBands(t1)[20,]
        dn       mavg         up       pctB 
-1.0325626 10.5000000 22.0325626  0.9118772
```

Now for the manual bands using the sd function.

```
> c(mean(t1)-sd(t1)*2,mean(t1)+sd(t1)*2)
[1] -1.33216 22.33216
```

The difference is because the sd uses the (n-1) method for the standard deviation and BBands uses the N method.

The question is how can I get the BBands function to use the (n-1) method.
The documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TTR/versions/0.23-3/topics/BBands) does not list such an option.

If it is not possible BBands, can someone help me make a function that clones BBands, but with (n-1) for the standard deviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The function**

You get the plain function code when you just write the function `BBands`(without brackets):

```
function (HLC, n = 20, maType, sd = 2, ...) 
{
    HLC <- try.xts(HLC, error = as.matrix)
    if (NCOL(HLC) == 3) {
        if (is.xts(HLC)) {
            xa <- xcoredata(HLC)
            HLC <- xts(apply(HLC, 1, mean), index(HLC))
            xcoredata(HLC) <- xa
        }
        else {
            HLC <- apply(HLC, 1, mean)
        }
    }
    else if (NCOL(HLC) != 1) {
        stop("Price series must be either High-Low-Close, or Close/univariate.")
    }
    maArgs <- list(n = n, ...)
    if (missing(maType)) {
        maType <- "SMA"
    }
    mavg <- do.call(maType, c(list(HLC), maArgs))
    sdev <- runSD(HLC, n, sample = FALSE)
    up <- mavg + sd * sdev
    dn <- mavg - sd * sdev
    pctB <- (HLC - dn)/(up - dn)
    res <- cbind(dn, mavg, up, pctB)
    colnames(res) <- c("dn", "mavg", "up", "pctB")
    reclass(res, HLC)
}
```

**Let's change the function**

there is the variable `sdev` with the function `runSD()`, i changed it to the function sdev <- as.vector(rollapplyr(HLC, n, sd))`, so we get a vector output. Let's call that new function BBands_2:

```
BBands_2 <- function (HLC, n = 20, maType, sd = 2, ...)

{
  HLC <- try.xts(HLC, error = as.matrix)
  if (NCOL(HLC) == 3) {
    if (is.xts(HLC)) {
      xa <- xcoredata(HLC)
      HLC <- xts(apply(HLC, 1, mean), index(HLC))
      xcoredata(HLC) <- xa
    }
    else {
      HLC <- apply(HLC, 1, mean)
    }
  }
  else if (NCOL(HLC) != 1) {
    stop("Price series must be either High-Low-Close, or Close/univariate.")
  }
  maArgs <- list(n = n, ...)
  if (missing(maType)) {
    maType <- "SMA"
  }
  mavg <- do.call(maType, c(list(HLC), maArgs))
  sdev <- as.vector(rollapplyr(HLC, n, sd))
  up <- mavg + sd * sdev
  dn <- mavg - sd * sdev
  pctB <- (HLC - dn)/(up - dn)
  res <- cbind(dn, mavg, up, pctB)
  colnames(res) <- c("dn", "mavg", "up", "pctB")
  reclass(res, HLC)
}
```

Now you can just copy that function in your code. You also need to activate the `library(xts)` and of course `library(TTR)`

**Result**

result with BBands_2:

```
df <- 1:20

BBands_2(df)[20,]
        dn       mavg         up       pctB 
-1.3321596 10.5000000 22.3321596  0.9014483
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great, and much easier than I thought. I did not know about calling a function without brackets to get its code. I knew it could be done just not how. Thank you again.

Comment: Also, BBands_2 is much faster than BBands, because sd() is much faster than runSD(). Thanks again.

Comment: I needed to change the sdev line to `sdev <- as.vector(rollapplyr(HLC, n, sd))`  because sd() is not a vector function. So it gives the same result, or the last calculation when used on a vector. I could not get apply to work so I used rollapply and as.vector to avoid and array warning. Please add this to your answer.

Comment: Glad i could help, i thought about problems with the vector output, but i don't know enough about BBands. The solution with just sd() gave intended output of the question, that's why i asked for feedback. Nice solution you found there :)